# Excel Find this Value and this Value and where they meet enter the new value

Tags: excel

Hi Guys I know I should know this but I am haveing a brain freeze!

So in sheet1 I have a list of people and each coloumn = a date

```
Emp No. Rota    01/04/2018  02/04/2018  03/04/2018  04/04/2018  05/04/2018  06/04/2018  07/04/2018  08/04/2018  09/04/2018  10/04/2018  11/04/2018  12/04/2018  13/04/2018  14/04/2018  15/04/2018  16/04/2018  17/04/2018  18/04/2018  19/04/2018  20/04/2018  21/04/2018  22/04/2018
10087248    1                                                                                       
10111378    1                                                                                       
10104720    1                                                                                       
10103818    1                                                                                       
10128761    1                                                                                       
10109686    1                                                                                       
10110853    1                                                                                       
10123778    1                                                                                       
10105003    1                                                                                       
10115410    1                                                                                       
10109674    1                                                                                       
10117543    1                                                                                       
10114185    1                                                                                       
10105990    1                                                                                       
10114457    1                                                                                       
10087185    1                                                                                       
10121055    1
```

in sheet 2 I have a list of dates and then each coloumn = a team

```
Date    1   2   3   4   5   7A  7B  R1  E1
Mon 01/01/2018  06:00   14:00   14:00   06:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   14:00
Tue 02/01/2018  06:00   14:00   14:00   06:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   14:00
Wed 03/01/2018      14:00   14:00   06:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   14:00
Thu 04/01/2018  06:00   14:00   14:00   06:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   14:00
Fri 05/01/2018  06:00   14:00       06:00   14:00       14:00   08:00   14:00
Sat 06/01/2018                                  
Sun 07/01/2018  14:00   06:00               18:00           
Mon 08/01/2018  14:00   06:00   06:00   14:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   08:00
Tue 09/01/2018  14:00   06:00   06:00   14:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   08:00
Wed 10/01/2018  14:00       06:00   14:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   08:00
Thu 11/01/2018  14:00   06:00   06:00   14:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   08:00
Fri 12/01/2018      06:00   06:00   14:00   14:00       14:00   08:00   08:00
Sat 13/01/2018                                  
Sun 14/01/2018      14:00       06:00       18:00           
Mon 15/01/2018  06:00   14:00   14:00   06:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   14:00
Tue 16/01/2018  06:00   14:00   14:00   06:00   14:00   18:00   18:00   08:00   14:00
```

I want to be able to see when the person is due to start in sheet 1.

I am trying to use index match but cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need some common denominator in your data sheet.
That means, in both Table1 and Table2  you need a column to contain the same data which will act as your criteria range.

Then it appears you need to use `=VLOOKUP()`

Can't really help you further without you editing either your Sheet1 or Sheet2 to have at least 1 column in common,
As of now, you have no way of matching something to a specific number given there are no possible matches (unless I'm missunderstanding what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: Its not in a coloum but but date and Rota are used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I cheated I made the dates match so both start from 01/03/2018 then I fliped the Rota so both tables had the date across the top and then just used =VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet3!$A:$QN,COUNT($C$1:C$1,FALSE))